# How to get task id in tokio with tokio_unstable

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to compile the following code,

```
let id = tokio::task::id();
```

I have enabled both "rt" feature and tokio_unstable. But it's giving me an error like the following

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `id` in module `tokio::task`
--> xxxx\src\util\utils.rs:27:35
|
27 | let id = tokio::task::id();
| ^^ not found in `tokio::task`
|
help: consider importing this function
|
1 | use std::process::id;
|
help: if you import `id`, refer to it directly
|
27 - let id = tokio::task::id();
27 + let id = id();
|
```

What should I do to fix this ?

Comment: How have you configured rt and tokio_unstable? Did you follow the instructions [here](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/index.html#unstable-features)?

Comment: I'm seeing "--cfg tokio_unstable" flag is passed into rustc. (have configured via both env variable and .cargo/config.toml). and "rt" is set as tokio = { version = "1.21.2", features = ["sync", "macros","rt"] } . (FYI this is a workspace if it's helpful)

Comment: hmm, weird `RUSTFLAGS="--cfg tokio_unstable" cargo check` works for me, but curiously having it in `.cargo/config.toml` does not... :/

Comment: oh nevermind, the `config.toml` works for me as well (I had an errant `RUSTFLAGS` env variable that was preventing it from using that)